# Перевернуть строку с русскими буквами

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");

    string str;
    cout << "введите строку оканчивающуюся точкой:";
    cin >> str;

    string str_reverse;
    for (int i = str.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        str_reverse = str_reverse.append(1, str[i]);
    }

    cout << str_reverse;
    return 0;
}
```

При введение строки русскими алфавитом выдаёт символы. Как исправить, чтобы выводило русскими буквами? С англисйким алфавитом всё работает прекрасно.

Comment: Наверное у вас кодировка utf-8. В ней русские буквы кодируются парой байт. Вообще, в этой кодировке количество старших единичных бит в первом байте кода задает число байт в коде символа, а все байты символа, кроме первого, начинаются с 10. Все ascii символы (цифры, латинские буквы и т.п. будут занимать 1 байт и иметь старший бит 0. (Теперь у вас есть вся необходимая для reverse  (вы же с конца строки к ее началу идете) информация...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если еще интересно, набросал кодик....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void
reverse_utf (char *src, int len, char *res)
{
  unsigned char *s = src;
  int j = 0;
  
  for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (s[i] < 128)
      res[j++] = s[i];
    else {
      int n = 1;
      while ((s[i] & 0xc0) == 0x80)
        i--, n++;
      int k = i;
      while (n--)
        res[j++] = s[i++];
      i = k;
    }
  }
  res[j] = 0;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  if (ac < 2) 
    exit((puts("Nothing to do"), 1));

  puts("Reverse strings:");
  for (int i = 1; i < ac; i++) {
    puts(av[i]);
    int l = strlen(av[i]);
    char *r = strdup(av[i]);
    reverse_utf(av[i], l, r);
    puts(r);
    free(r);
  }

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Компилируем и запускаем:

```
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$ gcc t-utf-revstr.c
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 123 й2ц3у ф
Reverse strings:
123
321
й2ц3у
у3ц2й
ф
ф
End
```